# Assigning a value to PHP object property

Tags: php

I'm working through a course on PHP and I'm completely stuck on one of the tasks.

The bit i'm stuck on is:

"PalprimeChecker *[a function created just for this task]* objects have a property called number. This task has two parts. First, assign that property a value of 17...."

The code I've written is returning an error and won't let me progress...

```
include('class.palprimechecker.php');


$checker = new PalprimeChecker();
$checker->number = '17';

echo "The number " . "$checker";
echo "(is|is not)";
echo " a palprime.";
```

I'm not sure at all where I'm going wrong with this.  Anyone know the correct way to assign this value?

Hope you can help as I'm tearing my hair out!

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: And can you show us your class code?

Comment: What do you expect `"$checker"` to do? The object probably has no string representation to echo. You can `echo $checker->number`, or if you want to inspect the object, use `var_dump`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What's working?  What's not working?  What does "won't let me progress" mean?  Do you get an error?  What is it?  Why are you trying to echo `$checker`?  That's not a string.  Does `PalprimeChecker` have a `__toString` method?

Comment: The class code isn't available, sorry!  No specific error message is being given (it's all done in a sandbox in the browser!).

I think my echo statement is where I'm going wrong.  Is that the correct way to concatenate the value '17' from the $checker variable?

Cheers

Comment: @user2191622: No, it's not.  The value `17` is stored in `$checker->number`.  You want to print that: `echo "The number " . $checker->number;`

Answer (score 9):

Modify this :

```
echo "The number " . "$checker";
```

By This :

```
echo "The number " . $checker->number;
```

You were trying to print the entire object (which isn't possible without creating a method for it, check orangePill's answer for this), what you wanted to do is simply print the number inside the object.

Also note that you don't need to use quotes when assigning numbers. It might cause issues later on. You should simply assign it like this :

```
$checker->number = 17;
```

Comment: Cheers!  Gotcha.  I think I need to do some proper reading on this.  The tutorial has skipped lightly over what seems a little tricky to grasp to this noob!

Comment: Glad it helped, don't forget to accept an answer and upvote other relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a __toString method on the PalprimeChecker class.

```
public function __toString(){
      return (string)$this->number;
}
```

This will allow `echo "The number " . $checker;` to produce a string.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the concatenation.

```
<?php


include("class.palprimechecker.php");
$checker = new PalprimeChecker;
$checker->number = 17;

echo "The number" . $checker->number . "";
echo "(is|is not)";
echo " a palprime.";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *are* assigning a string, and not a number.

```
$checker->number = 17; //Note that there are no quotes around '17'.
```